# How to compile single java file in maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, compilation

I want to count the number of test classes with compiler error in a project. To do this I need to compile independent test classes (.java files) one by one. Is there any way to do this. cannot do thos with javac as the dependent libraries for the test classes different. Any solution to achieve my target?

Comment: Testing with maven should show you exactly how many tests failed and where. There is a log file created for every single test file.

Comment: Ben 21 these are converted test cases and need to check the compilation errors only. Is there any way"?